# Read the 'Enabled' state of a button

Tags: .net, winforms, button, autoit

How do I get the `Enabled` state of a button (disabled/dimmed or enabled) in [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt)? It *does* work for property `Text`, but it *seems* not to work (always the same result no matter the button's state) for property `Enabled` ("properties" as in the .NET Windows Forms sense in Visual Studio).

This for a .NET application (Windows Forms, VB.NET) where the name of the button in the Visual Studio designer is `btnStoreInModule` and property text is `S&tore in Module`. The property [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx) is what I am interested in. The button is of type [`System.Windows.Forms.Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). My AutoIt script presses the button like this:

```
ControlClick("My Application", "", "[NAME:btnStoreInModule]")
```

The application responds by disabling the button while it is doing an operation. When the operation finished, the button is enabled again (undimmed). The application when the `Store` button is disabled:

[image: Button in a disabled state. For a .NET application]

[AutoIt Window Information Tool](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) gives the same result for both the disabled- and the enabled state:

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:    My Application 1.2a6
Class:    WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.b7ab7b
Position: -4, 34
Size:     1448, 870
Style:    0x17CF0000
ExStyle:  0x00050100
Handle:   0x000C08DE

>>>> Control <<<<
Class:               WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.b7ab7b
Instance:            21
ClassnameNN:         WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.b7ab7b21
Name:                btnStoreInModule
Advanced (Class):    [NAME:btnStoreInModule]
ID:                  592026
Text:                S&tore in Module
Position:            257, 675
Size:                91, 23
ControlClick Coords: 59, 8
Style:               0x5601000B
ExStyle:             0x00000000
Handle:              0x0009089A
```

I *can* get the text of a TextBox control using (`TB_Type` is the name of the text box in Visual Studio's property window (property *"Name"*)):

```
Local $sText = ControlGetText ("My Application", "", "[NAME:TB_Type]")
```

For the button the corresponding line returns `S&tore in Module` (as one might expect).

AutoIt version: 3.3.8.1 (2012-01-29).

Comment: I suspect a bug in AutoIt (for reading the Enabled state).

Comment: Note: Referring to user interface elements by the same name in AutoIt as in [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) works fine (AutoIt is .NET aware, I presume). Example: "btnStoreInModule" in Visual Studio's Designer with that Windows Forms application open (the actual code is `Me.btnStoreInModules.Name = "btnStoreInModules"`) and "[NAME:btnStoreInModule]" in AutoIt (yes, the brackets are part of the specification for AutoIt).

Comment: Unstable names (change on every build), like `WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.b7ab7b21`,  are not necessary.

Comment: To be clear, it ought to work according to the documentation, but it doesn't seem to (at least not in that version of AutoIt). Long-standing bugs are usually not fixed in AutoIt, so it may or may not still be a problem.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [ControlCommand](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlCommand.htm) function like this:

```
    $isControlEnabled = ControlCommand($hWin, "", "[NAME:button2]", "IsEnabled", "")
```

The function will return => 1 if `"[NAME:button2]"` is enabled and 0 if it is disabled.

Comment: Shouldn't "button2" be "btnStoreInModule"?

Comment: Buttons don't have names.  They have text ("St&ore in Module"), they might have a control ID when used in a dialog.  Which is best, use Spy++ (et al) to see the ID.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Buttons do have names in an AutoIt context (I use them in my AutoIt scripts in calls to ControlGetHandle(), ControlClick(), etc.  - though keyboard shortcut are often more reliable due to window/dialog). I can get the 'Text' property using the name, but not the Enabled property.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work:

```
Local $isControlEnabled = ControlCommand("My Application 1.2a6", "", "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.b7ab7b21", "IsEnabled")
ConsoleWrite($isControlEnabled)
```

The function will return 1 if the button is Enabled and 0 if it is Disabled.

Comment: Re *"should work"*? Did you test it? What version of AutoIt did you use? I suspect a bug in AutoIt (at least in that version of AutoIt), and the ID form may or may not make a difference.